# Finding an optimized Query in PLSQL

Tags: mysql, plsql, coding-style

Here the below data example,i have same scenario in real time.

```
p1  A(True)
p1  B
p1  C
p2  B(True)
p2  C
```

In Above 5 rows, There are two unique values `p1,p2.`

I want result on below criteria

1. All rows which has value 'A'
2. Rows which has value 'B' only in case when 'A' is not available.

**Expected output:

```
p1 A
p2 B**
```

I have found this by a long query, can anyone tell more optimized method to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you as expected output

```
select unique_value,output
from unique_data
 where 
        case
                when output ='A' Then 1 
                else output ='B'
        end
group by unique_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use follow query:

```
SELECT t.id,
         MIN(t.val)
  FROM TEST_TABLE t
 GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(val) IN ('A', 'B');
```

Table data:

```
id  val
-------
p1  A
p1  B
p1  C
p2  B
p2  C
p3  C
p3  D
```

Result:

```
id  val
-------
p1  A
p2  B
```